# Не отрабатывает флаг B в команде start bat файла

Tags: bat, powershell

Пытаюсь написать вызов консольной программы в окне батника, код следующий:

```
cd /d "K:\test_compile\aug"
start /W /B studiomdl.exe "K:\test_compile\aug\v_aug.qc"
pause
```

В результате программа запускается всё равно в новом консольном окне.
Что самое интересное, если использую диск `C:`  то всё работает, однако мне нужно, что бы файл находился не только на диске `C:`, сам батник генерируется автоматически.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что на диске `K:` в процессе стоит в совместимости `Запуск от имени администратора` по этому открывалось новое окно. Получается, что бы флаг работал, процесс должен быть запущен от одного пользователя, что и консоль.